# Python api - Rotate selected around vertex using bpy operator

Tags: python, transforms, operator, bmesh, transform-orientation

I want to rotate a selected item around a specific vertex like this:

```
 vertex.select=true
 bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=1)
```

This code basically rotates at the bounding box center.
I have tried setting the pivot point cursor and manually setting the cursor but this does not work.

```
bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point = 'CURSOR'
bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = (1,1,1)
    
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=1)
```

The result is still a rotation with axis at the objects center point.

I'm looking for a simple, scripting level solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bpy.ops.transform.rotate()` rotates on the object's origin.

You can  do `bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=yourValue,center_override=(x,y,z))` where x, y and z are the x, y and z of the vertex.

Basically the center_override overrides the rotation pivot position.

Comment: Amazing! I can't believe I missed that!